# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\\Collection::update()

Tags: php, mongodb

I updated a environment. I upgraded PHP and Mongo. The code was using the legacy driver but now I'm using mongodb. I'm also using mongo-php-library. This code snippet is broken now and I'm not sure how to fix it. I've read about updateOne and replaceOne but I'm not sure how to use it:

```
    function update($collection,$criteria,$data,$insertIfNotExists = false)
{
    if (!isset($this->collection[$collection])) {
        $this->collection[$collection] = self::$database->selectCollection($collection);
    }
    if ($insertIfNotExists) {
        $oldData = $this->collection[$collection]->findOne($criteria);
        if ($oldData == NULL) {
            $data['createdDate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['modifiedDate'] = (isset($data['modifiedDate'])) ? $data['modifiedDate']:date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            return ($this->collection[$collection]->insert($data)) ? array('status'=>'ok'):array('status'=>'error','error'=>'unknown_error');
        } else {
            $newData = $oldData;
            foreach($data as $n=>$v) {
                $newData[$n] = $v;
            }
            $newData['modifiedDate'] = (isset($newData['modifiedDate'])) ? $newData['modifiedDate']:date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            return ($this->collection[$collection]->update($criteria,$newData)) ? array('status'=>'ok'):array('status'=>'error','error'=>'unknown_error');
        }
    } else {
        return ($this->collection[$collection]->update($criteria,$data)) ? array('status'=>'ok'):array('status'=>'error','error'=>'unknown_error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new driver changed the name of some methods. Instead of `update()` (that was used to update one or more documents), now you have `updateOne()` and `updateMany()`. The same applies to the other legacy methods `insert()` and `remove()`. You can get all further information you need on these changes in [PHP MongoDB's Extension Docs](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/set.mongodb.php)  and in [MongoDB PHP Library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/).

So, just changing to the code below would fix that error:

```
$this->collection[$collection]->updateOne($criteria,$data)
```

**Edit**
Seems that you only need to update the field `modifiedDate`, so you can do the following:

```
$criteria = ['number' => '999'];
$newData = ['modifiedDate' => '2019-07-11 03:00:00'];
$this->collection[$collection]->updateOne(
    $criteria,
    '$set' => $newData
);
```

More info here: [Update One Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#update-one-document)

Comment: can you check my updated question with the variable data for $criteria & $newData

Comment: I get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException: First key in $update argument is not an update operator`

Comment: It appears that you are trying to update the entire document. In this case, try `$this->collection[$collection]->replaceOne($criteria,$data)`

Comment: So you should update only the fields that you need that be updated. I'll edit my answer to give you an example

Comment: I am `$this->collection[$collection]->findOne($criteria);` so I'd rather not do that.

Comment: You mention `insert()` and `remove()` what would I replace those with?

Comment: Your latest update does something to the `collection` where I have to mongoimport to fix

Comment: @robertparkerx, I'm very sorry that you had problems with your data. Too, I'm sorry if it was not your intention with that comment but, please, don't put the blame on me. The edit I made was to provide you an **example** of what to do, I never said "ctr-c ctrl-v these lines to your code and it will work". I answered correctly your original question and added links that would, for sure, solve the further doubts you posted here as comments. I truly recommend you to read those links, as they can give you a better understanding on how MongoDB works. Cheers

Comment: No that is not what I meant. I just don't understand.

Comment: So, everything is ok. Please, take a look a the links in my answer. They are full of examples that will help you to address those further doubts you have about the code. []'s